# how to add mysql to path global variables

Tags: mysql, path

I have recently installed MySQL and am trying to access it through my command prompt by simply typing in MySQL.

I believe I need to add it to my `PATH` globals. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd.exe and enter

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Now you can scroll to the PATH variable and edit it.

For that, just put an `;` at the end of the old value, and add the path of the mysql\bin folder behind it.

You need to close and restart your current cmd instaces, to use the new PATH.