# Modifying the System Path variable from cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, path

I am trying to modify my system Path value.
I need this as I am doing an upgrade of the S/W and the users need to have access to the old and new system. I provide them with a toggle button which will change the settings and let them use both.

One of the things I need to do for this is change the system path value.
I have a .reg file to do this. When I run this script, I get the message 
"The keys and values contained in  have been successfully added to the registry"

But I do not see the change reflected when I go and check my registry.

My Original value for System Path is:

```
C:\Oracle01\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Infor\Unify\Runtime52\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\
```

My reg file is as below

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"Path"="REG_EXPAND_SZ:C:\Oracle01\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Visual\RunTime40\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\"
```

---

I want entry C:\Infor\Unify\Runtime52\ to change to c:\Visual\RunTime40\ in the path.

Pls let me know what I am missing here. My reg file is in my local C drive.

Thanks,
Vidya.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the situation here but can you not edit or add new environmental variables?

Comment: system path or registry key? they are very different, one you do via regedit <file>.reg and the other via SET

Comment: I want to edit the system Path. I tried changing the registry for it.

Comment: I finally tried this and it worked. 
SETX -M PATH "C:\Oracle01\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Visual\RunTime40\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\"     

I now want to put this in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

As in comments

To change your local paths you do it via console, you use SET commands, so with it you can

**View your available enviroment variable list**

```
SET
```

**Create a new env variable**

```
SET newenv=hello;
```

**Update a variable**

```
SET newenv=%newenv%cya;
```

**Can pint it out**

```
echo %newenv%
SET %newenv%
```

At system registry keys

you can

```
registry /s <file>.reg
```

`/s` is for silent.

Comment: I finally tried this and it worked. 

SETX -M PATH "C:\Oracle01\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Visual\RunTime40\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\"

Comment: I now want to put this in a batch file.
I have admin rights , so I did not have to run as admin.
In case of other users without admin access will this work?

Comment: can't accurate it , anyway I can't understand your environment. You seems to be at an enterprise network, If so , as domain admin you can remote execute everything

Comment: You can see answers to this [question].(http://superuser.com/questions/758950/how-to-add-mysql-to-path-global-variables) and this(http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)